# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'isOnline' of undefined

Tags: javascript, sencha-touch-2

```
Ext.define('MyApp.util.batch', {
    singleton : true,
    config:{
    },
    testFun: function(){
        multi =new MyApp.util.batch.runBatchProcess();
        var run = function (delay) {
            Ext.create('Ext.util.DelayedTask', function () {

                multi.start();
                run(100000);
            }).delay(delay);
        };
        run(3000);
},
runBatchProcess: function(){
    var batchObj=new Object();
    var start = function(){ 
        console.log('start');
        if(Ext.device.Connection.isOnline()) {     //error at this line
            alert('isonline');
        } else {
            alert('offline');
        }

    };
    batchObj.start = start;
    return batchObj;
}
});
```

Getting error at the line with comment.
Error at console is: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'isOnline' of undefined
Not getting the reason for it.
Any help would be appreciated. 
:)

Comment: Means `Ext.device.Connection` is undefined. Did you include it?

Comment: what is the reason for that? what i have to do to remove this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Been awhile since I have used this framework, but looks like you did not include the needed file

```
Ext.require('Ext.device.Connection');
```

Comment: i have added: requires : [
  'Ext.device.Connection'
       ],
above config:{}

Answer (score 0):

For whatever reason, it doesn't seem like `Ext.device.Connection` isn't included inside the default `sencha-touch-all-debug.js` and `sencha-touch-all.js` files that come w/ the download of the latest version (2.3.1) of Sencha Touch... so you'll have to include it manually.

Comment: requires : [ 'Ext.device.Connection' ]  seems not enough because won't work for me.